# How to offset in Excel Macro Active.Cell.Offset function that changes X cells to the right based upon the contents of a cell result

Tags: excel

I currently use the following function:

ActiveCell.Offset(10,-8).Range("A1").Select      to move 8 cells over.

But now I need to sometimes move anywhere from 8 to 75 cells based upon the contents of cell "$DA$3".
How do I make my "8" in my original formula VARIABLE?

Mark

I don't have a clue how to do this!

Comment: Is this just a small macro to offset where you are from a hotkey or is this part of a bigger sub? If so, can we see the actual sub because usually you don't need to use ActiveCell.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a variable...

Here's a simple example that demonstrates the solution:

```
Sub dynamic_offset_demo()

row_shift = 10
column_shift = Range("$DA$3").Value

result = ActiveCell.Offset(row_shift, column_shift)
Debug.Print result

End Sub
```

In this example, I just extracted the target cell value. If you also want to select the cell, you can use the following line, which seems simpler that what you've used in your original question:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(row_shift, column_shift).select
```